# _context.SaveChanges() works but await _context.SaveChangesAsync() doesn't

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-2.2, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I'm struggling to understand something. I have a .Net Core 2.2 Web API, with a MySQL 8 database, and using the Pomelo library to connect to MySQL Server.

I have a PUT action method that looks like this:

```
// PUT: api/Persons/5
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PutPerson([FromRoute] int id, Person person)
{
    if (id != person.Id)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    _context.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Modified;

    try
    {
        _context.SaveChanges(); // Works
        // await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); // Doesn't work
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!PersonExists(id))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return NoContent();
}
```

As per my comments in the code snippet above, when I call *_context.SaveChanges()*, it works (i.e. it updates the relevant record in the MySQL database, and returns a 1) but when I call *await _context.SaveChangesAsync()*, it doesn't work (it does not update the record, and it returns a 0). It's not throwing an exception or anything - it just doesn't update the record.

Any ideas?

Comment: There's something else going on here. `SaveChanges` *literally* just calls `SaveChangesAsync` and blocks on that until it returns. There is no true non-async access in EF Core.

Comment: I completely agree with you. I can't for the life of me explain it! :/ Perhaps it's a bug in Pomelo?

Answer (score 5):

As I said in my comment above, EF Core has no true sync methods. The sync methods (e.g. `SaveChanges`) merely block on the async methods (e.g. `SaveChangesAsync`). As such, it's impossible that `SaveChanges` would work, if `SaveChangesAsync` doesn't, as the former just proxies to the latter. There's some other issue at at play here, which is not evident from the code you've provided.

However, the reason I'm writing this as an answer is that the way you're doing this, in general, is wrong, and I believe by doing it right, the problem may disappear. You should never and I mean never directly save an instance created from the request body directly into your database. This provides an attack vector that would allow a malicious user to alter your database in undesirable ways. You've covered that partially by checking the id has not been modified, but a user could still alter things they should not be allowed to.

That security vulnerability aside, there's a practical reason not to do it this way. An API serves as an anti-corruption layer, but only if you decouple your entity from the object the client interacts with. When you use your entity directly, you're tightly coupling your database to your API layer, such that any change at the database level necessitates a new version of your API, and worse, provides no opportunity for deprecating the previous version. All clients must immediately update or their implementations will break. By exposing a DTO class instead to your client, the database can evolve independently of the API, as you can add any anti-corruption logic necessary to bridge the gap between the two.

Long and short, this is how your method should be structured:

```
// PUT: api/Persons/5
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PutPerson([FromRoute] int id, PersonModel model)
{
     // not necessary if using `[ApiController]`
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest();

    var person = await _context.People.FindAsync(id);
    if (person == null)
        return NotFound();

    // map `model` onto `person`

    try
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        // use an optimistic concurrency strategy from:
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency#resolving-concurrency-conflicts
    }

    return NoContent();
}
```

I wanted to keep the code straight-forward, but for handling optimistic concurrency, I'd actually recommend using the Polly exception handling library. You can set up retry policies with that which can keep trying to make the update after error correction. Otherwise, you'd need try/catch within try/catch within try/catch, etc. Also, the `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` is something you should always handle in some way, so re-throwing it makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed post Chris. I appreciate it, and i completely agree with you. I will try this out and get back to you asap.

Answer (score 5):

I'm truly sorry to anyone who's time I have wasted with this question. I figured out the problem, and it was a stupid mistake I made in my dbContext. I have an audit trail setup, so I am overriding `SaveChangesAsync`, `OnBeforeSaveChanges` and `OnAfterSaveChanges`. There was a bug in that code. However, I am not overriding `SaveChanges`, which is why that still worked. Sorry!

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution!

Comment: You don't need apologize, you helped me too, now I know what check when SaveChanges and SaveChangesAsync have different results